# unable to locate resource: esapi-java-logging.properties

Tags: esapi

I upgrade the esapi version from 2.2.0.0 to 2.5.1.0. I have updates the esapi property file, added the esapi-java-logging.properties file but still its throwing error like unable to locate resource: esapi-java-logging.properties

Trying to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

This question is already asked at the ESAPI Discussions list on GitHub, specifically at:
https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/discussions/765
And Jeremiah Stacey has already attempted to answer your question. Furthermore, you don't really provide enough context to us to say that you are doing something wrong because there are others that are not having this problem. So, unless you can provide more detail / context or tell us specifically how to reproduce the issue, I don't think we can provide an further assistance that what Jeremiah already provided at the aforementioned link.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is about 3 months old, but still decided to answer as I had the same issue and could find a solution. I found that the class loading issues in my application was the culprit.
I have a war packaged in a EAR and within the EAR/lib, I had placed the upgraded ESAPI jar, but my mistake was that I had placed the properties files in the war/web-inf/resources folder and class loader was not able to locate it. I moved the ESAPI jar to the war/WEB-INF/lib folder and everything worked as expected.